# Terraform - Process to Update vendor aws-sdk-go dependencies to latest

Tags: go, aws-sdk, terraform, aws-sdk-go

Hi I am trying to understand as how to update the aws-sdk-go dependencies for terraform. To do this i have configured the

1. GOPATH as per instruction given below.

   http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/12/easy-go-programming-setup-for-windows/
2. I have installed and configured "godep" in $path.
   So now i am able to run "go" and "godep" from cmd.

as per development terraform section\guideline given at
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform i have git cloned
it at  `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform`

again as per guideline i just want to update aws-sdk-go deps. so i am running

```
godep update github.com\aws\aws-sdk-go
```

getting below message on cmd

```
godep: not in manifest: github.com\aws\aws-sdk-go

godep: Package (github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest) not found
```

I have also verified that path

```
 D:\Ampush\Projects\GO\src\github.com\hashicorp\terraform\vendor\github.com\Azure\azure-sdk-for-go\Godeps\_workspace\src\github.com\Azure\go-autorest\autorest
```

exists on my machine.

I am running command from below path

```
D:\Ampush\Projects\GO\src\github.com\hashicorp\terraform>
```

Updating this further with more findings

if i run first godep restore -v then it has downloaded many stuffs.
then i figured out that my command was wrong now i updated it to

```
godep update github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws  //hint saw in Godep.json
```

Now i am getting

```
godep: no packages can be updated
```

i guess that somewhere i have to mention as to which version i should update default i was assuming it will take latest from the master.

[image: cmd image]
Could you please let me know if i am missing something. Thanks

Comment: Added more finding in the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

`godep update` will update the vendored version from your global gopath version. To get the latest version in your gopath run something like `go get -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go` then you can run your `godep update`

Comment: yes i have called go get -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go after this i can see latest aws-sdk-go in my \github.com\aws\aws-sdk-go . Then i called godep update however getting message as no package can be updated. added the image in the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: with more googling i think the idea is as below to update the deps                go get [your deps]
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/[deps path]
godep save . then we should able to see latest version in Godep.json file . in my case its coming as blank . trying to figure out as why?

Comment: Is aws-sdk-go in your `Godeps/Godeps.json` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to cd into your deps, you should be able to just do everything in the main folder of your app. I should note that I have never used godeps on windows, and I don't know if that is the cause of the problem or not, it shouldn't be.

Comment: I am now able to call go get -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go and godep update. But to do this i had to call go get ./... before as per link hint  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766457/godep-save-seems-not-working-for-https-github-com-hashicorp-terraform/35766543?noredirect=1#comment59206420_35766543

Comment: Now next i can see Godeps/Godeps.json has latest deps which i have verified with git  master. Now when i call godep go build it should replace my old deps with new one  but this is not happening. any guess for this ?