# godep save ./... seems not working for https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform

Tags: go, terraform

Hi i am following the link https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform . As per given section "Adding a dependency"  i have successfully run below commands

```
git checkout master
git pull
godep restore -v # flag is optional, enables verbose output
git checkout my-feature-branch
git rebase master
```

Now when i run

```
godep save ./...
```

i am getting few packages not found. 
[image]

if i manually update this package with go get then it looks another one and so on.. 
Please let me know how can i run this successfully thanks

Answer (score 1):

`godeps` requires the dependencies to be already in your `GOPATH`. If you haven't downloaded the dependencies (yet), first run

```
go get ./...
```

Then you can run

```
godep save ./...
```

Comment: Thanks.. yes this is the command i was looking for which will feed all deps. I ran now  go get ./... now getting                                                                              as   D:\Ampush\ALM\Terraform\dummy\go>go get ./...
package artifactory.v401: unrecognized import path "artifactory.v401" (https fetch: Get https://artifactory.v401?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup artifactory.v401: getaddrinfow: No such host is known.)

Comment: That's another error. Please open a different question and post the code relevant to debug the error.

Comment: Thanks Simone. i will do that